# x64 inline assembly in C

Tags: c, assembly

I am trying to code [the sum of natural numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) using inline x64 assembly in C but it isn't working.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int unsigned(n)
{
    __asm__
    {
            mov     ecx, n;
            mov     eax, 0;
            cmp     ecx, 0;
            je ende;
    label:
            add eax, ecx;
            loop label;

    ende:

    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
summer.c:4:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
```

And also how can I define the `n` variable? Is it better to do it in the inline assembly or in the C code?

Comment: if that works, it is only because a compiler supports it... what compiler are you using?

Comment: also I don't see anything very 64 bitty about that asm

Comment: @GradyPlayer I use nasm

Comment: Pro tip: write the code in C first, test/debug it, then generate asm using `gcc -S ...`. You can then either use the generated code "as is", or as a starting point for your own code.

Comment: @PaulR the problem is I am also a newbie in C so I think in the could be even more difficult

Comment: @Kate `nasm` is an assembler and expects pure assembly as input. You have a C source file with inline assembly, which means you need to compile it with a C compiler.

Comment: @AndrewMedico bu i think it is possible to link it to a c prog  calls the assembler and print outs the result so the C do only call and return

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible to compile the asm and C separately, but (1) that's no longer "inline" you stated in your question, which makes things a bit confusing, and (2) you can't put C includes and a C function definition in the asm file.

Comment: Start by learning basics of C (or programming in general). Assembly is much harder to do properly (that's the reason higher level languages were invented in the first place).

Comment: @Groo       #include <stdio.h>
      int gauss(int n)
      {
         __asm
        {
             mov eax, n;
             inc eax;
             imul eax,n;
             shr eax,1;
     
         }

    }

that also don't work

Comment: @Kate: that's a different question, but also not a good one. Where did you get these snippets from? Throwing in a bunch of statements you don't understand and then building to see what happens is a bad idea. How about: `int gauss(int n) { return n*(n+1)/2; }`?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is complaining because your function declaration doesn't make sense. `unsigned` is a reserved keyword, call your function in some other way; also, you have to specify the type of the parameter.

```
int f(int n) 
{
   ...
```

As for the assembly, the syntax depends from the toolchain you are using, depending from it you may have to use the hideous AT & T. syntax (or to specify some magic command to switch to Intel syntax and back).

(by the way, `xor eax, eax` is more idiomatic than `mov eax, 0`)

Comment: No, as stated, `unsigned` is a reserved keyword (it's used to specify `unsigned` integral types), and you cannot use it as a function name.

Comment: Correct. You need to use a non-reserved word for your function, maybe `sum` or `gauss`.

Comment: @AndrewMedico yes but after changing this I get more errors:(

Comment: @Kate: is it barfing on register names? Then probably your compiler is set up to use AT&T syntax. Anyhow, you should post these problems in a new question, specifying the compiler you use and the errors you get.